# How to make 2 or 3 xml sitemaps in drupal for example for different taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, xml-sitemap

I need to generate 4 sitemaps which differ in content included in them according to certain taxonomies! XML sitemap can generate one sitemap. When I try to generate other it displays error: A sitemap with the same context already exists.

Comment: I assume you are using the XML Sitemap module?

Comment: What's wrong with a single sitemap ? They are not for humans right ?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest installing the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module. It will allow you to create XML pages from your taxonomy and as many as you want.

I would create one view and 4 page displays with the varying filters to generate your pages.  Then change the output to XML.

I looked over the XML Sitemap, and the error you are experiencing seems to be something they are trying to troubleshoot. You can follow [along there](http://drupal.org/node/939812), or try some of their methods.

Comment: Would this be able to hook into the XML Sitemap module, so that the sitemap index file would be made?

Comment: Well I just looked at the XML Site map module and you should be able to create more than one sitemap.

Comment: Edited with a new link for you to read.

Comment: I think it will be best solution to use Views Data Export, Thank you all! Thank you iLLin!